# Query @property values in ManyToMany relationships

Tags: django, methods, model, properties

I need to query certain fields in a ManyToMany relationship. Here is the setup;

```
class Yacht(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    multiplier = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    yachts = models.ManyToManyField(Yacht, through='Result')
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Result(models.Model):
    yacht = models.ForeignKey(Yacht, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    result = models.FloatField()

    @property
    def result_adjusted(self):
        # returns the adjusted result based on the yacht's multiplier
        return self.result * self.yacht.multiplier
```

Question: How can I query the adjusted result for a given yacht in a given event?

Answer (score 1):

One cannot query properties **but** One can bring the *logic* of the property into the query and use that instead.

Suppose we want `Result` instances where `result_adjusted` is let's say 6, then we will write a query like:

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, F, FloatField


results = Result.objects.annotate(
    result_adjusted_value=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('result') * F('yacht__multiplier'),
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
).filter(result_adjusted_value=6)
```

References:

[`annotate` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) (can be replaced with [`alias` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#alias))

[`F()` expressions [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)

[`ExpressionWrapper` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions)

Comment: Where would you insert this logic? In the models file or views?

Comment: @JulienEast this is a query so of course it should reside in a view.

Comment: Also, that is filtering for a known result_adjusted. In most instances, I would need to filter by yacht for a given event.

Comment: I eventually intend to use this in the Admin panel as a TabularInline form. Is there a method or technique that can be used so that the result_adjusted is always added as part of the object?

Comment: @JulienEast you can either use a [Custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset) or you can specify [ModelAdmin.get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) for your model admin

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement a custom manager and access that queryset from admin.

Comment: Can a custom manager return all objects with their result_adusted?